# Make reading RDS from stdin independent whether the file was created via pipe or not

Tags: r

```
readRDS=function(file = pipe('cat', 'rb'), ...) {
    base::readRDS(file, ...)
}
saveRDS=function(object, file = pipe('cat', 'wb'), ...) {
    base::saveRDS(object, file, ...)
}
```

I use the above function to read an RDS file from stdin and write an RDS file to stdout.

See below, one readRDS call works, the other doesn't. It depends on whether the rds file is written using pipe or not.

```
$ lr -e 'source("saveRDS.R"); saveRDS(1:3, file="/tmp/readRDS.rds");'
$ lr -e 'source("readRDS.R"); print(readRDS());' < /tmp/readRDS.rds
Error in base::readRDS(file, ...) : unknown input format
$ lr -e 'source("saveRDS.R"); saveRDS(1:3);' > /tmp/readRDS.rds
$ lr -e 'source("readRDS.R"); print(readRDS());' < /tmp/readRDS.rds
[1] 1 2 3
```

Why does it depend on the way the file is written? Is there a way to make readRDS from stdin always work whether the file is written via pipe or not?

Comment: Aside - Avoid naming a user-defined method the *same* name as a known method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a difference between compression between the two methods. Rather than reading from `cat` in the `readRDS` Try

```
readRDS=function(file = base::gzcon(base::file("stdin", "rb")), ...) {
    base::readRDS(file, ...)
}
```

The `gzcon` will do the compression if the gz magic number is found, otherwise it will just pass through the file normally. This should allow things to work in both cases.

Comment: BTW, regarding saveRDS, is my definition OK? Or it is better to be changed so that it does not depend on a pipe?

Comment: I am trying to replace the pipe with gzcon for  saveRDS  `saveRDS=function(object, file = base::gzcon(base::file('/dev/stdout', 'wb')), ...) {
    base::saveRDS(object, file, ...)
  }`. I can not get it work. Do you know how to make the modification so that saveRDS directly save to an rds file without via a pipe?

Comment: I don't know what change to suggest to `saveRDS` I can't seem to find a way to open a binary compressed connection to standard out. I would have thought `gzfile()` would do the trick but it doesn't seem to understand "stdout" as a file name